# Bizarre anchor tag / relative pathing issue in Plone

Tags: plone

Using Plone 4.1.4.

Have a container called /employment which has a default view of a page also called employment.

There's an additional page in the employment container called foo

When I add anchor tags (either via TinyMCE or straight html) it "automagically" links to the parent folder instead of the current page.

I'm on `http://www.example.com/employment/foo`
I try and add a link `<a href="#bar">` on the foo page.

I'd expect the link to be `http://www.example.com/employment/foo#bar` when rendered
BUT instead it's showing up as `http://www.example.com/employment/#bar`

Any idea why it's defaulting to the parent "folder" instead of the page its currently actually on? Is it some weird caching issue or url rewriting voodoo?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but: In the tinyMCE settings->resource type, I noticed the "Contains Anchors" list doesn't include "pages" (i'm still learning plone's terminology - I assume that's a content type) My list of "Contains Anchors" includes: 

`Event
News Item
Document
ATRelativePathCriterion`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Link using UIDs" enabled in TinyMCE's settings? UID-linking enables a URL-rewriting filter, which resolves all relative links to absolute ones. Id had issues with relative links, but those should be fixed in *plone.outputfilters >= 1.2* (e.g. it doesn't try to "fix" anchor links anymore).

Comment: Thanks! I do have "Link using UIDs" enabled for TinyMCE. If I were to uncheck that setting, would it only effect how future links are created, correct? I don't want to orphan all the previously UID-linked links. I'll also look at updating plone.outputfilters ASAP.

Comment: FWIW: Unchecking link using UIDs and then editing a page to add a fresh anchor link didn't work/exhibited the same behavior :( I'll report back on the output filter later.

Comment: When exactly does the link go broken? Does it break in TinyMCE? (Clicking HTML-source again shows that it's immediately broken.) Or only when Plone renders the page? (The link continues to show correctly on TinyMCE when editing the page again, but comes out broken when the saved page is viewed.) The former would be a TinyMCE-problem, the latter either an outputfilter or base-tag problem. If the link is broken already in the source code of a rendered page, it could be an outputfilter problem. If the link look correct on source, but is broken by the browser, it could be base-tag problem.

Comment: A few more questions :) Are the content types (container and page) in question default Plone content types or custom ones (Archetypes or Dexterity?). And have you manage to reproduce this with a vanilla Plone installation? (I failed to reproduce this.)

Comment: The page should just be a normal plone archetype. The link "breaks" after it's saved/published and then viewed. The HTML looks fine before I save it - breaks when rendered. I haven't tried to reproduce in vanilla plone...  I'll report back when I know conclusively if the the plone.outputfilter update helped or if we find a different root cause in case others stumble upon this issue in the future. (but currently no new news to report)

Answer (score 0):

You might be falling victim to a base tag here. The base tag is used by browsers to decide the reference point for relative links. If the base tag says that the base URL is your container, then the relative links you create will end up being rendered relative to that.

Check the value of base in the head of your rendered page to see if this is the case.

Comment: During my research I did some see chatter about this "issue" in an old mailing list thread:  

 http://copilotco.com/mail-archives/plone-users.2007/msg00696.html

The base link looks correct to me in the rendered source (showing the current page, and not the parent directory), though...

Answer (score 0):

This was still relevant issue for me working with dexterity content types in Plone 4.3.3.

At first the anchor links worked normally when I created a non-folderish content type. But the anchor links behaviour changed after I converted it to folderish container type.

After seeing the answer by Cris, I believe that the base tag changes according the type of the content if it is folderish or not. Yet the navigation links (e.g. in portlet nav tree) don't. This brakes the usage of anchor links.

[A ticket](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13705) has been submitted about this, and the resolution seems to be to remove the base tag completely in plone 5.0.

For plone 4.3.3. I can only think of using absolute urls for the anchor links in my folderish content type's template.

```
<a tal:attributes="href string:${context/absolute_url}#anchor">My Anchor</a>
```